# Embedded linux distribution builder similar to QNX build scripts

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, qnx

I've been working with yocto linux and recently started working on QNX, where the creation/customization of distribution contents (rootfs) is really simple - basically there is a single script/build file (http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.building/topic/buildfiles/buildfile_syntax.html) that defines what ends up in final rootfs. This approach is really useful for building simple systems and i was wondering if there is something similar to QNX build scripts for embedded linux distributions? Compared to build scripts, the yocto bitbake scripts are extremely complicated...

Comment: There is always trade between simplicity and flexibility. Have you tried [buildroot](https://buildroot.org)?

Comment: Asking for SW recommendations is off-topic.  Vote to close.